# How do we know which field we get in $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

In $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$, we could have $\theta = \sqrt[3]{2}$, but can we not also have $\theta' = \sqrt[3]{2}\omega_3$, where $\omega_3$ is the primitive third root of unity, or $\theta'' = \sqrt[3]{2}\omega_3^2$?

I have learned that the fields $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2}\omega_3)$ are isomorphic, but not equal. Is there a way to know which field we are talking about? Or is it for some reason irrelevant?

Comment: Isomorphic means there is no algebraic way to distinguish them. All you can say about that field is that it is obtained from the rationals by adjoining an entity whose third power is two.

Comment: To put it another way, a field whose elements are cosets of the ideal generated by $x^3-2$ can be isomorphic to, but can't be equal to, a field whose elements are real and/or complex numbers.

Comment: A different way to think about this is to say there are three possible embeddings into the complex numbers, one of which happens to lie inside the real numbers.

Comment: Do you understand the situation now, SKY?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yeah, I think I was confused because I thought the "isomorphic, yet unequal" meant that $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3-2)$ was not well defined.